# Display Only One Item from Database at a time and Loop through other in time cycle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am having a project, to display some details on Main Screen of my office, but problem is that I want to display only Item a time and then cycle through each item in time period.

Below is my php, Java Sciptis and index page.

index.html

```
<ul></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/my_script.js"></script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
        include_once('db.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = array();

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
            array_push($result, array('ID' => $row[0],
                                      'Name'  => $row[1],
                          'Post' => $row[2]));

        echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
?>
```

my_script.js

```
$(document).ready( function(){
done(); 

});

function done() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        updates();
        done();
        },200);

}

function updates() {
$.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
    $("ul").empty();

    $.each(data.result,function(){
        $("ul").append("<li>ID: "+this['ID']+"</li><li>Name: "+this['Name']+"</li><li>Designation: "+this['Post']+"</li><br />");
    });
}); 
}
```

**I have not wrote this script. SO I need some help** As the above script will display items without refreshing it, I want to display only on item at a time.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to call `updates()` every 200 ms?

Comment: No I want to display only 1 item in a table at a time and cycle through other items in 5 or 10 seconds say

Comment: Ok thanks. But I don't still understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean `at cycle through other items...`? Could you show us an example?

Comment: If is not necessary to call every time a SQL query, you can just call one time DB query to save all the json data. Then you can use setInterval to iterate the data by index, this could be an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z6gLE/

Comment: @naota I have a table with 4 coloumns..say id,name,add,phone I want to display one 1 entry at a time in my html page. I have used jQuery so that, i can retrieve data without refreshing my web page.
It jus like display SLA projections or Bdays or TAT score in company...

Comment: @AlexBall your script works..but my motive is to display only one at a time..means John is displayed..then after interval of 1000ms it should disappear and Anna must be shown...

Comment: @user3766876 OK. The idea of AlexBall looks fine for me. I made a little change for his JSFiddle. How about this : http://jsfiddle.net/z6gLE/2/

Comment: @naota Thanks Buddy!!!!!!!!!!! It works...thats what I wanted!!!

Comment: Just another question..if want to connect a database to the above Fiddle instead of dynamic names..what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I think this will work for you.  It fetches the data once, when the page loads, and then loops infinitely (starting from the beginning again when it reaches the end of the data).

```
var i = 0; // index of data to iterate.
var d = null; // where we store the result of the query.
var interval = 1000; // interval in ms.

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // get the data *once* when the page loads.
    $.getJSON('fetch.php', function(data)
    {
        // store the data in the global var 'd'.
        d = data.result;

        // create a recurring call to update().
        setInterval(function()
        {
            update();
        },
        interval);
    });
});

function update()
{
    // if there isn't another element, reset to the first one.
    if (!d[i]) i = 0;

    // remove previous item from page.
    $('ul').empty();

    // add next item to page.
    $("ul")
        .append(
            '<li>ID: ' + d[i]['ID']
            + '</li><li>Name: ' + d[i]['Name']
            + '</li><li>Designation: ' + d[i]['Post']
            + '</li>'
        );

    // increment index for next iteration.
    i++;
}
```

---

***Alternative version that re-fetches after reaching the last record***

```
var i = 0, // index of data to iterate.
    d = null, // where we store the result of the query.
    x = null, // stored interval so clearInterval() can be used.
    interval = 1000; // interval in ms.


$(document).ready(function()
{
    fetch();
});

function fetch()
{
    // get the data *once* when the page loads.
    $.getJSON('fetch.php', function(data)
    {
        // store the data in the global var 'd'.
        d = data.result;

        // create a recurring call to update().
        x = setInterval(function()
        {
            update();
        },
        interval);
    });
}

function update()
{
    // if there isn't an array element, reset to the first one.
    if (!d[i]) {
        clearInterval(x);
        i = 0;
        fetch();
        return;
    }

    // remove previous item from page.
    $('ul').empty();

    // add next item to page.
    $("ul")
        .append(
            '<li>ID: ' + d[i]['ID']
            + '</li><li>Name: ' + d[i]['Name']
            + '</li><li>Designation: ' + d[i]['Post']
            + '</li>'
        );

    // increment index for next iteration.
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah man..thats what I wanted!!! exactly...but the problem is  that it fetched only once...i want it to fetch continuously because 62 or more of user will be updating their scores individually...

Comment: Good answer. One improvement would be to re-fetch data when you iterated trough all the records (maybe when you reach the last but one record?). This will avoid going out of sync in case the database is often updated.

Comment: Fetching continuously might be a problem. For example if you show the first 5 users and then a new user is added at position 2, you will repeat the display of user 5 as they are now user 6. Is your data relatively 'static' (that is, number and order of users doesn't change frequently)?

Comment: No they won't change order...but I think what @B0Andrew said..how can I refetch the data after last iteration?

Comment: See my edit that provides an alternative version with the re-fetch as suggested by @B0Andrew

Comment: @timclutton...Love you man...!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lottt buddyy!!! My Boss is gonna be happy now!!!! Thanks a lot